# Explanation of finding values a, b that $\sin$, $\cos$ continuous

Tags: continuity

Could you explain finding continuity of the function on this example:

$$\ f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(x+a), & x \in \left(n \pi, (n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\right] \\ \cos(x+b), & x \in \left((n+\frac{1}{2})\pi, (n+1)\pi\right]
  \end{cases} ?$$

I got confused so I would appreciate your help. I got messed at trigonometrric function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include where you got confused, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to assure of continuity, we have to obtain:

$$\ \sin(x+a) = \cos(x+b)  $$
From formulas of the sum of the angles in sin and cos, we have
$$\ \sin(x+a) = \cos(x+b)  $$
$$\ \sin(n\pi+a) = \cos(n\pi+b)  $$ fpr x = $n\pi$
$$\ \sin(n\pi+a) = \sin(n\pi)\cos(a)+\sin(a)\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n\sin(a)  $$
$$\ \cos(n\pi+b) = \cos(n\pi)\cos(a)-\sin(a)\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n\cos(b)  $$
$$\ sina=cosb $$
Similarly we act for $\ x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and get $\cos(a)=-\sin(b)$

$$\ \sin(x+a) = \cos(x+b)  $$ is satisfied when $\ a = \frac{\pi}{2} + b + 2k\pi $ or $\ a = \frac{\pi}{2} - b + 2k\pi $

$\cos(a)=-\sin(b)$ is satisfied when $\ a = \frac{\pi}{2} + b + 2k\pi $ or $\ a = \frac{3\pi}{2} - b + 2k\pi $

Therefore the function is continuous everywhere if $\ a = \frac{\pi}{2} + b + 2k\pi $,

continuous in x = $\ n\pi $ and not in $\ x=n\pi+\frac {\pi}{2}$, if $\ a = \frac{\pi}{2} - b + 2k\pi $

continuous in $\ x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ and not in x = $\ n\pi $, if $\ a = \frac{3\pi}{2} - b + 2k\pi = a = -\frac{\pi}{2} - b + 2k\pi $